# The API (java/io/File.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V) reads a file whose location might be specified by user input

Tags: file, security, sonarqube, owasp

Following is the implementation in the code:

Gets the truststore location and password from the database:

```java
 SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(
                        new File(trustStoreLocation)trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
```

Using sonar for static analysis of code. Getting an error in sonar saying 'reads a file whose location might be specified by user input'. How to resolve this vulnerability? Tried various solutions but still got the same error. Can anyone please help me?

Solutions tried : `FileNameUtils.getName()`, `normalize()`
Since not sure how the path should start couldn't try `getCanonicalPath()` or `Path.resolve()`.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this sonar vulnerability?